# Вывод данных из БД на Java Servlet

Tags: servlet, java, jsp

Всем привет, возникла такая проблема с выводом данных из БД. Понять в чем проблема не могу.

Есть сервлет:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
            java.io.IOException {

        List<News> newsArray = new ArrayList<News>();

        try {

            db = new DatabaseConnector();
            rs = db.query("SELECT * FROM news ");
            while (rs.next()) {
                News news = new News();
                news.setName(rs.getString("Name"));
                news.setGame(rs.getString("Date"));
                news.setContent(rs.getString("content"));
                newsArray.add(news);
                System.out.println("-----------------------------------" + news.getName());
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        request.setAttribute("newsArray", newsArray);

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext()
                .getRequestDispatcher("news.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Есть jsp страница:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/index.css">

<title>Sports</title>

</head>

<body background="image/test.jpg" >
    <div id="top"><img src="image/top.png" width="100%"
            height="100%"></div>
    <div id="menu"><%@ include file="menu.jsp"%></div>
    <div id="content">

<table width="40%" border="1">
            <tr width="40% " align="left">
                    <td width="40% " align="left"> <FONT face="Comic Sans MS" color="#FF4500">Title</FONT></td>
                    <td width="40%" align="left"><FONT face="Comic Sans MS" color="#FF4500">Content</FONT></td>
                    <td width="40%" align="left"><FONT face="Comic Sans MS" color="#FF4500">Date</FONT></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
        <c:forEach var="news" items="${newsArray}">
            <table width="40%" border="1">
                <tr width="40% " align="left">
                    <td width="40% " align="left">${news.Name}</td>
                    <td width="40%" align="left">${news.content}</td>
                    <td width="40%" align="left">${news.Date}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </c:forEach>

    </div>
    <div id="right">
     <c:if test="${sessionScope.LoggedIn == null}">
<%@ include file="autorization.jsp"%>         </c:if>

        <c:if test="${sessionScope.LoggedIn}">
            <%@ include file="usermenu.jsp"%>
        </c:if>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Вроде все нормально, никаких ошибок. Но при запуске выдает следующее:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> org.jazzteam.action.ShowNews.doGet(ShowNews.java:49)
>   at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
>   at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
>   at
> org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>   at
> org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:401)
>   at
> org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>   at
> org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>   at
> org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
>   at
> org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
>   at
> org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
>   at
> org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
>   at
> org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>   at
> org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
>   at
> org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>   at
> org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
>   at
> org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
>   at
> org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
>   at
> org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
>   at
> org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
>   at
> org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

Вот строчка из сервлета на что ругается:

dispatcher.forward(request, response);

Данны из БД достают, проверял через консоль.

Comment: проверьте dispatcher на null

Answer (score 2):

А что за строчка №49 в `doGet()`? Очень похоже что возвращается нулевой `RecordSet` или `Db`, проверьте куда смотрит `DatabaseConnector` в дескрипторе. Такое ощущение что неверно задан путь JNDI

Comment: dispatcher.forward(request, response); вот эта строчка.


в конекторе вроде все нормально, к бд конект проходит отлично. Данные в newsArray ложатся и достаются.